# an api to retrieve information about different phones?

Tags: javascript, python, android, node.js, compare

Hey does anyone knows about an api for retrieving information about mobile phones like (ram, rom, processor, camera ,etc).

- i have tried web scraping but it is not helpful for different products.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using an android phone you can take help from the below URL.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html.

Comment: i want this information for a phone comparing website project